# Siri's phonetic fields

Tags: iphone, ios, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, siri

Is there a way or a tool to check how Apple's Siri would interpret/read the value of phonetic field? I've been able to help myself a little with `say something` in terminal (Mac OSX) but I'm curious of any other alternatives.

I've been adding phonetic representation of different names to various fields on iPhone 4S (nickname, phonetic first name, phonetic last name). I got some of them right but I'm still struggling with some (local) names.

For example I can't figure out how to write surname Pečar. It should sound like the first two letters from the word PEsimist + Char. I've tried 'Pe Char', 'Pee Char', 'Pea Char' but first two letters are always pronounced to close to PIss.

Comment: Does 'pehchar' work for Pečar? OS X's `say` command seems to handle that one. I don't believe there's a canonical pronunciation guide for phonetic fields.

Comment: That's pretty close Piers. Thanks a lot! Though not exactly how I'd say its probably the closest we can get for now.Do you have any useful universal tips to share? I'm sure you don't want me to make a list of all my weird names :)

Comment: Is this programming related? If this is more a question of how to use (advanced features of) an iPhone, perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is a better venue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This isn't a real answer, but since it seems to have helped I'll post it as an answer for the credit!)

Does 'pehchar' work for Pečar? OS X's say command seems to handle that one. I don't believe there's a canonical pronunciation guide for phonetic fields.

Maybe you could update your question to include some more specifics of pronunciations you're having trouble with. That way we can start building a phonetic-spelling guide.